# How can a bash script run several others scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I try to make a bash script to run multiple scripts located in different directories.

I tried to do something like

```
#!/bin/bash  

path1="/path/to/folder1"
path2="/path/to/folder2"
command="./script"

command_line="cd $path1 -exec $command {} \; cd $path2 -exec $command {} \;"

echo $command_line
eval $command_line

exit
```

But no luck.. as you can imagine, my bash skills are close to .. 0

Comment: If you want to run the scripts, why can't you just… run them? (`cd "$path" && ./script`) Can you be more specific about what you really need to accomplish? This seems somewhat contrived.

Comment: Well I have like 20 folders in which a script is present. Instead to have to go to each of the folder every time I reboot, I would like to have only one "global" script to initiate

Comment: I think this might help you (an explanation as to why your cd commands aren't working as expected): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: actually the cd'ing seemed to be working except I want the script to pass to the next directory before the execution of the sub script is finished.( it s video encoding and takes a while). The routine should be: cd to subfolder, start the subscript, pass to the next folder, start the subscript.. and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Main problems with your script.

1. cd  doesn't take any more parameters. So the rest of the line after the directory name will be ignored (here, -exec $command ...)
2. exec  (I don't know what -exec means here) will run the command in place of the parent process, ie, your main script will be replaced by  and rest of your script will not run anymore.

Each command should be like this: "cd $pathx; $command". Since you don't want to be blocked, you have to run it in the background "(cd $pathx; $command) &"

Now you want to do that for 20 folders, you might what to run a loop, something like this:

```
for p in `cat file-containing-folder-names`
do
  (cd $p; $command) &
done
```

Remember that 20 different processes are spawned here. Make sure it doesn't go out of control.

Comment: A few tips: 1) There's a useless use of `cat` here. 2) Ideally, `$p` should be [quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (but it doesn't help if the `for` splits paths with spaces into two arguments). 3) Instead of `for`, one should [iterate over lines in a file with `while`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Finally, there's a nice guide on what the OP wants to achieve: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I tried to follow your solution http://pastebin.com/1qRbmeui but curiously, only the first 2 scripts are triggered. When I added path 3 and 4, nothing happened there

Comment: @slhck: I didn't understand the 'useless use of cat' comment.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUOC#Useless_use_of_cat) for an explanation. You rarely need `cat` unless you want to concatenate files (much like you rarely need `for` unless you work with shell globs or arrays as arguments). It spawns an unnecessary process. You can achieve the same thing with `while read -r p; do …; done < filename` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for the explanation. I too don't use `cat` redundantly otherwise. In this case, if I am using `for`, can `cat` be avoided? I understand `while` is better, but want to know if `cat` can be avoided if `for` is used.

Comment: No, with `for` you cannot avoid it, but that's because `for` was not meant for working with files, whereas `read` is.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks. Good to learn about `while .. read` instead of `for`.